# PWA reset password link on Android device, when selecting to open with App

Tags: android, hyperlink, asp.net-core-mvc, progressive-web-apps

We have a PWA app that adds the APP Icon for the PWA onto an Android devices home page (as expected). In the app we have a login with a reset password option if the user has forgotten their password

When an email is sent to the user with a link back to the ResetPassword page, opening the link on an adroid device gives the following:
[image]

If you open with the actual PWA App, then it ignores the page link address and just directs directly to the startup page for the PWA

If you open with Chrome then the correct page is displayed.

Why would opening with the PWA App ignore the location of the Link? Anyone?

Comment: How does your password reset link look like?

Comment: https://pwaapp.zestit.co.nz/ResetPassword.html?userid=16&code=CfDJ8GW3Of%2bDKQhJjJvWPuQCIh0hznKgMmSKcFpAF77Jico4CyoB2Ex5P24BvdIijNMbyNV2uSTbkEuFhtcfc%2bIkjrqbtAHGz5zJmC8KiC0L%2bBzzIh6g4U7zTht%2bPDfKxMXcMQY1PibauUJuZKrEO9R%2bovMUDhgAxmR75hR32vRBb8o8vSJFCCcTlycADAv886moqg%3d%3d

Note I altered the actual address of the URL as this is an active website

Answer (score 0):

PWA always loads the URL given in start_url attribute in manifect.json file. With the Intent filters, you can make your PWA open on clicking relevant URL or domain.

Look at "Effectively managing your app's scope" section [in this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen) on how scoping and start URL works.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to make the start URL dynamic with the user requested URL in this case.

Comment: what would be ideal is if you could specify an exclude directory under the PWA address that if called actually went to the page in the browser rather than open in the APP

Comment: You can achieve it little trickily. Create a sub-domain, say myapp.mydomain.com and map all the paths that PWA have to support and set the scope to that sub domain. With that, what you said can be achieved.  It can get a bit tedious depending on your possible paths. But unfortunately, there is no explicit PWA solution for the same.